# Cannot get com.huawei.hms.location.LocationServices for Huawei Map Kit in android studio

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, huawei-map-kit, huawei-location-kit

I am currently trying to migrate **Google Maps** to **Huawei map** kit in my android project.

It was easy to migrate google maps to Huawei map at first. They are provided all the methods and classes that Google Maps have but now I couldn't get **LocationServises** class from Huawei that I used in my google maps.

In the documentation they say that **Huawei Map kit** has ***`com.huawei.hms.location`*** package and `LocationServises` inside. But why I cannot get it???

The links and libs that I added to  gradle below: I refer the Huawei Map Kit documentation

```
 1. maven {url 'https://developer.huawei.com/repo/'} 

 2. classpath 'com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.2.1.301'

 3. maven {url 'https://developer.huawei.com/repo/'} 

 4. implementation 'com.huawei.hms:maps:5.1.0.300'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the location services in the following artifactory

`// Huawei implementation "com.huawei.hms:location:4.0.3.301"`

And retrieve the location with:
`FusedLocationProviderClient`

Retrieve the last location with the listener

```
private var fusedLocationProviderClient: FusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context)

fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation.addOnSuccessListener { location -> Log.d("Location", location)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I am finally getting the LocationServises class in Huawei but there something is missing.
I am migrating the Google maps to Huawei map and in the google version there is something like `public static final Api<NoOptions> API;` variable inside LocationServises class and I need this variable in Huawei too. But there no variable like this :/ do you know where to get it? Is this the same class in Huawei or different than Google?
Thank you again for your answer

Answer (score 1):

1. You are advised to use [Huawei Location Kit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides-V5/introduction-0000001050706106-V5?ha_source=hms1) because Map Kit involves only some of location functions. :)
2. 

> I am migrating the Google maps to Huawei map and in the google version
> there is something like public static final Api API;
> variable inside LocationServises class and I need this variable in
> Huawei too. But there no variable like this :/ do you know where to
> get it?

Please kindly refer to the [Location Kit References](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References-V5/locationservice-0000001050746175-V5?ha_source=hms1).

About `public enum LocationType`, please refer to docs [here](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References-V5/api-locationtype-0000001050154741-V5?ha_source=hms1).